# How to draw lines with detects collision itself?

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I want to create line shape in box2d at runtime.  I did using Edgeshape but problem in collision with itself.

Is any other methods to create box2d line with detect collision with itself and other box2d object?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw line using Polygon shape with small height. Like this

```
b2PolygonShape shape;
b2BodyDef bd;
b2FixtureDef fdf;
    bd.type = b2_staticBody;
    bd.position.Set(5, 10);
    shape.SetAsBox(200,.3);
    fdf.shape = &shape;
    fdf.density = 1;
    b2Body* bodyA = world->CreateBody(&bd);
    bodyA->CreateFixture(&fdf);
```

Comment: But i have to draw line with slight slope and whatever user wants to draw.

Comment: you can draw also slope by providing vertexes of box.

Comment: you can see box2dtestbed in testcpp Example of Dominos as well as varying Friction